# Ruby on Rails Route not found with button_to, but not with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to, button-to

I have a problem with routing in my app, but i do not understand why.
I hope someone can explain me why this is so.

thank you very much for help.

```
<%= link_to 'Show', restaurant_path(restaurant), :id => 'button_show_restaurant', :class => 'btn btn-success' %> 

<%= button_to 'Show', restaurant_path(restaurant), :id => 'button_show_restaurant', :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
```

The link_to code routes correctly to the needed restaurant, but the button_to produces the following:

No route matches [POST] "/de/restaurants/526fe01e65617271ea000000"
Trace:
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in`block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in`tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in`call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in`call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in`call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in`call'
passenger (4.0.21) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
passenger (4.0.21) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:140:in`accept_and_process_next_request'
passenger (4.0.21) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:108:in `main_loop'
passenger (4.0.21) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in`block (3 levels) in start_threads'

Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url
welcome_index_path   GET     (/:locale)/welcome(.:format)    welcome#index
POST     (/:locale)/welcome(.:format)    welcome#create
new_welcome_path     GET     (/:locale)/welcome/new(.:format)    welcome#new
edit_welcome_path    GET     (/:locale)/welcome/:id/edit(.:format)   welcome#edit
welcome_path     GET     (/:locale)/welcome/:id(.:format)    welcome#show
PATCH    (/:locale)/welcome/:id(.:format)    welcome#update
PUT  (/:locale)/welcome/:id(.:format)    welcome#update
DELETE   (/:locale)/welcome/:id(.:format)    welcome#destroy
restaurants_path     GET     (/:locale)/restaurants(.:format)    restaurants#index
POST     (/:locale)/restaurants(.:format)    restaurants#create
new_restaurant_path  GET     (/:locale)/restaurants/new(.:format)    restaurants#new
edit_restaurant_path     GET     (/:locale)/restaurants/:id/edit(.:format)   restaurants#edit
restaurant_path  GET     (/:locale)/restaurants/:id(.:format)    restaurants#show
PATCH    (/:locale)/restaurants/:id(.:format)    restaurants#update
PUT  (/:locale)/restaurants/:id(.:format)    restaurants#update
DELETE   (/:locale)/restaurants/:id(.:format)    restaurants#destroy
root_path    GET     /   welcome#index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `button_to` does a post while `link_to` does a get. So you want this

```
<%= button_to 'Show', restaurant_path(restaurant), :id => 'button_show_restaurant', :class => 'btn btn-success', :method => :get %>
```

Comment: Hi Vidya, 

thank you for your fast reply. It worked. Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!